# Forwarding template parameters and defines

Tags: jsf, facelets

Consider a nested template:

**Base.xhtml:**

```
...

<h:outputText value="#{uiParamter}"/>
<ui:insert name="header"/>

... etc.
```

**Layout.xhtml:**

```
<ui:composition template="Base.xhtml">

    ...

    <ui:insert name="content"/>

    ... etc.

</ui:composition>
```

When now defining a template client like this:

```
<ui:composition template="Layout.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="header"> foo </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content"> foo2 </ui:define>
    <ui:param name="uiParameter" value="foo3"/>

</ui:composition>
```

does one have to forward the `<ui:param>` or `<ui:define>` in the `Layout.xhtml` to the `Base.xhtml` template by redefining it. e.g:

```
<ui:param name="uiParameter" value="#{uiParameter}">  
<ui:define name="header">
    <ui:insert name="header"/>
</ui:define>
```

One could also rephrase this question as: *"Do template parameters behave cascading?"*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is YES. I've run the following code on JBoss AS 7.0:

**nest1.xhtml:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title><ui:insert name="title">
                Nested
            </ui:insert></title>
    </h:head>
    
    <h:body>
        <ui:insert name="main" />
        <h:outputText value="#{uiParam}"/>
    </h:body>

</html>
```

**nest2.xhtml:**

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" template="nest1.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="main">
        <p>Nested templated content.</p>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

**nest3.xhtml:**

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" template="nest2.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="title">Nested Template</ui:define>
    <ui:param name="uiParam" value="ui param value" />
</ui:composition>
```

which was rendered as:

[image: screenshot of jboss output]